# border for all divs

Tags: html

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<Style type="text/css">
#header{border:1px solid #000;}
#1{border:1px solid #000;
background-color:green;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script></script>
<div id="header">
<h1>...</h1>
</div><br>
<div id="1">
 <input type="text" name="JDate" placeholder="OnBoardDate"><br>
 <input type="text" name="RDate" placeholder="ReturnDate"><br>
 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not getting a border for the second `div`. In the developer console in chrome it's showing, but on webpage it is not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Another Id instead of Numeric.

```html
               <!Doctype html>
                <html>
                <head>
                <title></title>
                <Style type="text/css">
                #header{border:1px solid #000;}
                #new{ border:1px solid #000;
                background-color:green;}
                </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                <script></script>
                <div id="header">
                <h1>...</h1>
                </div><br>
                <div id="new">
                 <input type="text" name="JDate" placeholder="OnBoardDate"><br>
                 <input type="text" name="RDate" placeholder="ReturnDate"><br>
                 
                </div>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS class and id name can't start with numeric values. Use anything else like `<div id="first"></div>` and it will work.

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<Style type="text/css">
#header{border:1px solid #000;}
#first{border:1px solid #000;
background-color:green;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script></script>
<div id="header">
<h1>...</h1>
</div><br>
<div id="first">
 <input type="text" name="JDate" placeholder="OnBoardDate"><br>
 <input type="text" name="RDate" placeholder="ReturnDate"><br>
 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this help